# python code to remove duplicates or substrings of element from list

Tags: python

I have the following list as input:

```
['temp/date=20-07-2019/', 'temp/date=21-07-2019/', 'temp/date=22-07-2019/', 'temp/date=22-07-2019/temp=22-07-2019/']
```

In the output I want to exclude 'temp/date=22-07-2019/' since its a part of 'temp/date=22-07-2019/temp=22-07-2019/'. Hence the output should be:

```
['temp/date=20-07-2019/', 'temp/date=21-07-2019/', 'temp/date=22-07-2019/temp=22-07-2019/']
```

I have tried several ways but was not able to achieve this. Please suggest.
Thanks

Comment: you need only remove duplicates, am I right?

Comment: Might be helpful to show what ways you've tried.

Comment: clarify: could `'temp/date=22-07-2019/'` be placed somewhere in the middle/end of another item?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `any` with a list comprehension:

```
r = ['temp/date=20-07-2019/', 'temp/date=21-07-2019/', 'temp/date=22-07-2019/', 'temp/date=22-07-2019/temp=22-07-2019/']
result = [i for i in r if not any(i in c and len(c) > len(i) for c in r)]
```

Output:

```
['temp/date=20-07-2019/', 'temp/date=21-07-2019/', 'temp/date=22-07-2019/temp=22-07-2019/']
```

Comment: This would not remove duplicates. You could turn the list into a set first to eliminate duplicates, then perform the list comprehension for substring

Answer (score 1):

In case your items have specific format (`temp/date=DD-MM-YY/`):

```
d = {}
lst = ['temp/date=20-07-2019/', 'temp/date=21-07-2019/',
       'temp/date=22-07-2019/', 'temp/date=22-07-2019/temp=22-07-2019/']

for s in lst:
    k = s[:21]
    if k not in d or len(s) > len(d[k]):
        d[k] = s

print(list(d.values()))
```

The output:

```
['temp/date=20-07-2019/', 'temp/date=21-07-2019/', 'temp/date=22-07-2019/temp=22-07-2019/']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary:

```
lst = ['temp/date=20-07-2019/', 'temp/date=21-07-2019/', 'temp/date=22-07-2019/', 'temp/date=22-07-2019/temp=22-07-2019/']
dct = {re.match(r'(temp/.+?)/.*', i).group(1): i for i in sorted(lst, key=len)}
# {'temp/date=20-07-2019': 'temp/date=20-07-2019/', 'temp/date=21-07-2019': 'temp/date=21-07-2019/', 'temp/date=22-07-2019': 'temp/date=22-07-2019/temp=22-07-2019/'}

print(list(dct.values()))
# ['temp/date=20-07-2019/', 'temp/date=21-07-2019/', 'temp/date=22-07-2019/temp=22-07-2019/']
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is also taking care of identical duplicates creating a set:

```
example_data = ['temp/date=20-07-2019/', 'temp/date=21-07-2019/', 'temp/date=22-07-2019/', 'temp/date=22-07-2019/temp=22-07-2019/']
# Creating a set we get rid of all identical entries
unique_data = set(example_data)
result = []

# Here we cycle through unique_data adding to result list all the long strings
# since we want to keep all the long entries
[result.append(item) for item in unique_data if len(item) > 21]

# Then we cycle again and take care of adding to result all the short strings that
# are not already contained in result items
for item in unique_data:
    if len(item) == 21:
        for element in result:
            if item != element[:21]:
                result.append(item)
            break

# I am not sure you need to sort by date but this can be easily achieved with sorted
print(sorted(result))
```